# Assign custom hotkey on any Google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, hotkeys

Is it possible to assign custom (own) hotkey on any Google chrome extension? Looking for in-box or 3-rd party solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type into your Chrome address bar: `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`.

Or use the link in the top left corner of `chrome://extensions` page, in the  navigation sidebar.

Note: "Activate the extension" acts the same as clicking on extension's toolbar button.

Comment: `chrome://extensions/configureCommands` has been changed to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`, and the link on the `chrome://extensions` page has been moved to the sidenav, which can be accessed from the top left corner. `configureCommands` still redirects to `shortcuts`, but might not in the future.

Comment: @Joakim Thank you for your suggestions, I've edited them in. Please feel free to use edit functionality on Stack Exchange sites to suggest updates to answers!

Comment: Note that one can't ***unset*** a shortcut if the extension sets a default. This is likely an [issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You need the following:

1. The extension ID of your extension.
2. A program to script the hotkey with (AutoHotkey for Windows, Keyboard Maestro for Mac or Autokey for Linux).
3. The script needs to open a link to your extension such as chrome-extension://iinhokidgfoomcighckbjmlcndbjmomp/options.html

You'll find the ID of your desired chrome extension in the Webstore - e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/**mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf**?hl=en

An AutoHotkey script for a hotkey like this would be:

```
F5:: ; Hotkey is F5 here
SendInput ^t ; open new tab
SendInput chrome-extension://iinhokidgfoomcighckbjmlcndbjmomp/options.html ; write the extension's address
SendInput {enter} ; press enter to confirm.
Return
```

I have toyed with the Shortcuts Manager extension to create a JavaScript command to open the extension, but my knowledge of JS is very limited and I was unsuccessful. I'll post an example code in a comment to this answer.

Comment: Here's an example of what I have tried: chrome.tabs.create({"url": "chrome-extension://iinhokidgfoomcighckbjmlcndbjmomp/options.html"});

Comment: It'd be nice to receive some feedback on this.